# Are these questions duplicates (exiting various git commands)?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Oldest question? (probably something more canonical is needed):

[How to exit a git status list in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696433/how-to-exit-a-git-status-list-in-terminal)

Duplicates?:

1. [How to stop/cancel command in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826770/how-to-stop-cancel-command-in-terminal)
2. [How do I exit the results of 'git diff' in Git Bash on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929457/how-do-i-exit-the-results-of-git-diff-in-git-bash-on-windows)
3. [Git diff - how to quit the diff listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568811/git-diff-how-to-quit-the-diff-listing)
4. [How to exit git log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483757/how-to-exit-git-log)
5. [Git and Dos - how to exit a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344748/git-and-dos-how-to-exit-a-command)

All of them are about exiting git commands (status/log/diff/etc) and all of them have same answer.

Comment: Sure, it is the kind of question where just typing the very brief answer is a lot quicker than locating and voting for the dup.  You can still vote but it is a waste of your time.  Maybe a moderator has time to merge them, not actually so sure that is a good idea.

Comment: @HansPassant Wait there's a reason _not_ to mark them as duplicates?

Comment: Nobody has voted yet.  So, yes.  Don't let that slow you down.